# Is there any proof of Hazrat Zain Ul Abideen mourning over Karbala in his entire life

Tags: history, islamic-scholar, islamic-events

Asalam o alaikum dear Muslim brothers and sisters. I wanted to know if there is any proof of Hazrat Zain Ul Abideen mourning over the incident of Karbala in his entire life? Like bringing out horses, hitting himself. Anything like that?

Answer (score -2):

Sure, here's a simplified explanation from the perspective of a Muslim scholar:

---

As-salamu alaykum. The event of Karbala was a very tragic one in Islamic history, and Imam Zain ul Abideen, who was present during this event, is known to have been deeply affected by it.

The historical accounts tell us that Imam Zain ul Abideen spent a lot of time remembering the martyrs of Karbala, including his father Imam Hussain, through prayers and supplications. His collection of prayers, known as "Sahifa Sajjadiya," often reflects on the tragedy of Karbala.

However, as for the specific practices you mentioned, like bringing out horses or hitting oneself, these are cultural expressions of mourning that have developed much later in certain Shia communities. We don't have historical proof that Imam Zain ul Abideen himself did these particular things.

It's important to remember that the way people express their grief can differ greatly, especially across different cultures and times. Imam Zain ul Abideen expressed his sorrow and remembered the tragedy of Karbala in his own way, through his prayers and his life.

Comment: Which source did you use to write your answer? You should give a link to it.